# ReferenceError: handle is not defined at vm.js:1:1 (I have absolutely no clue)

Tags: coffeescript, referenceerror

I am just completely stuck. I need an extra set of eyes. I tried looking at this and I am just at a loss. What am I supposed to do? I would ask for help at cryptotrader but they will act like I'm stupid for not magically knowing the answer. Did I make a typo or something? Plus I need to keep typing just so this will let me post because it thinks it is mostly code.

```
trading = require "trading"
params = require "params"
talib = require "talib"

invest = params.add "Invest Amount in asset",.001
distance = params.add "Price change in asset",50
fees = params.add "Percentage of fees",.0025

init: ->
handle: ->
    instrument=data.instruments[0]
    asset = @portfolios[instrument.market].positions[instrument.asset()].amount
    base = @portfolios[instrument.market].positions[instrument.base()].amount/_.last(instrument.close)
    InsClose=_.last(instrument.close)
    balance=(base+asset)*InsClose
    storage.price?=InsClose
    if InsClose>(storage.price+distance)
        if asset/(1-fees)>=invest
            trading.sell(instrument,'limit',invest,InsClose)
            storage.price=storage.price+distance
            debug “Balance #{balance}”
    if InsClose<(storage.price-distance)
        if base/(1-fees)>=invest
            trading.buy(instrument,'limit',invest,InsClose)
            storage.price=storage.price-distance
            debug “Balance #{balance}”
    sellprice=storage.price+distance
    buyprice=storage.price-distance
    plot:
        sellprice:sellprice
        buyprice:buyprice
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is likely because you are defining an anonymous object with an `init` and `handle` method which now cannot be reached by any other code:

```
init: ->
handle: ->
```

Compiles to:

```
({
  init: function() {},
  handle: function() {}
});
```

You probably want this instead:

```
init = ->
handle = ->
```

Which compiles to:

```
var handle, init;

init = function() {};
handle = function() {};
```

If this doesn't help, please post the code where you call the handle method. If it's in a different file, include how you export and import / require the other file.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I forgot to define how long the order needs to be in effect before expiring. here it says trading.buy or trading.sell, I need one more parameter in the parentheses.